# Including global config in AngularJS module dependencies

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, browserify

I've developed an AngularJS app that uses browserify and injects modules as dependencies into the main app. In all of the modules I want to be able to access global configs from a routingConfig.js file.

Partial code:

main app.js

```
  var routingConfig = require('./common/config/routingConfig');

  module.exports = angular.module('app', [
    // modules as dependencies
    require('./home/home').name,
    require('./login/login').name
  ]);
```

module home.js

```
  var HomeCtrl = require('./homeController');

  module.exports = angular.module('app.home', [
    'home/home.tpl.html',
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'home/home.tpl.html',
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'Home'

          /**
           * I want to be able to use values from routingConfig here...
           */
        }
      });
  })
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', HomeCtrl]);
```

I could of course require routingConfig in every module, and that would work, but ideally I'd like to be able to just require it once and use it globally in the main app and its modules. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution came into my mind is following.

1) Create new module named as 'app.config' and use angular constant service (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) for registering and using of your config:

```
 var routingConfig = require('./common/config/routingConfig');

 module.exports = angular.module('app.config', [
 ])
 .constant('routingConfig', routingConfig);
```

2) Add this 'app.config' module to list of module dependencies in app.js

```
 module.exports = angular.module('app', [
   // modules as dependencies
   require('./config/routingConfig').name,
   require('./home/home').name,
   require('./login/login').name
 ]);
```

3) You could now inject routingConfig and use it:

```
 module.exports = angular.module('app.home', [
   'home/home.tpl.html',
   'ui.router'
 ])
 .config(function config($stateProvider, routingConfig) {

    ... use routingConfig here...
 });
```